# How to set boot device from Windows?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-server-2008

My USB keyboard does not work during BIOS setup, so I can't change my primary boot device.

Is there a way to set the primary boot device from Windows?

Is there any other way to boot from CD?

I don't have a PS2 keyboard handy.

P.S.: After I got into BIOS, I enabled the Legacy USB Support, and now my USB keyboard works just fine.

Comment: Tried using a usb to PS2 adapter?

Comment: yes, and it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short*: No.

*Long*: Windows can't control the BIOS. It's a very important concept of security to not allow the OS to change the BIOS. This is why boot-sector viruses were able to propagate.

*Lesson Learned*: If you know what PS/2 is, keep a PS/2 mouse and keyboard (or adapter) handy at all times.